# Error in GUID fields using "Simple Data Loader"

Tags: arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I have a replicated table in my SQL Server (PE_AMB_ANP), that table has a field named "rowguid" (rowguid is auto generated)

When I try yo load data, the field appear matched with 'none', but when the process continues it throws an error "duplicate key {0000-..}"

I don't want to update that field using ArcMap.

How can exclude "rowguid"?

[image: Feature Class Properties]

[image: Simple Data Loader throws an error]

Answer (score 1):

The unique GUID is what makes ArcGIS replication possible -- You cannot eliminate it.  You can certainly autopopulate a GUID value which isn't all-zeros (which should prevent duplicate keys).

Comment: Replication was not created using ArcGIS tools, it comes from a remote server with merge publication, I just want to ignore that field.

Comment: The error is from the database, not ArcGIS.  Populating a unique GUID will still address the issue.  Otherwise you'd need to drop the column.